# "funny you should ask"

Tags: comprehension, idioms

> *Q:* Is it ethical to send email to everyone who visits my Web site, or all of my customers?
>   *A:* **Funny you should ask**... seriously, though, it is often tempting for people to send
>   “bulk email” to large groups of people in order to pique their interest in a new feature
>   on their site, or let them know about a great deal they’re offering. You should
>   resist this temptation. You should never send bulk email to people who haven’t
>   given you permission to include them on your mailing list. Regardless of whether
>   such a practice is ethical, doing so will make you extremely unpopular with a significant
>   number of people.

How do you understand the part in bold?

Comment: Related: [_Funny-you-should-say-that_ on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206005/should-its-funny-you-should-say-that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It usually means there's a *coincidence* involved.  "Funny" in the sense "weird". The speaker has recently confronted a similar circumstance or was just now doing something related to the question.

Comment: As an example, let's say my son Bob has been dating a woman named Linda for awhile. One day, he calls me up, and announces that he and Linda have split up. The very next day, a friend asks, "How are Bob and Linda doing?" I might answer, "Funny you should ask; I just found out last night that they split up." If someone else asks me the same question about a month from now, I'm unlikely to start with, "Funny you should ask..." Instead, I'll probably just say something like, "Oh, they split up about a month or so ago."